# How to prevent a Gtk.SourceView from grabbing the URI of a file

Tags: gtk

I'm making a text editor using GTK3 in Vala. I need to drag a file and, when I drop it into the application window, the application opens that file. I'm using a `Gtk.Notebook` that contains the `Gtk.SourceView`'s. It works when I drop a file into an empty `Gtk.Notebook`, but when there is at least one `Gtk.SourceView` appended on it, the `SourceView` grabs the URI of the file, shows it and the window can't handle the opening of the file.

In this case, what can I do to prevent a `Gtk.SourceView` from grabbing the URI of a file when I drop a file into a `Gtk.SourceView`.

**PS:** I tried to use the `drag_dest_unset()` inside the `SourceView` derived class. It worked, the `SourceView` didn't grab the URI and the window could open the file, but the application showed a message like this, in runtime:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a target list on a widget until you've called gtk_drag_dest_set() to make the widget into a drag destination
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `Gtk.SourceView` stop grabbing the uri, I used the following code snippet:

```
public class MySourceView: Gtk.SourceView {
    public MySourceView() {
        Gtk.TargetEntry[] targets;
        targets = new Gtk.TargetEntry[1];
        targets[0].target = "text/uri-list";
        targets[0].flags = 0;
        targets[0].info = 0;

        Gtk.drag_dest_set(this, Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, targets, Gdk.DragAction.COPY);
        this.drag_data_received.connect(this.drag_data_received_cb);
    }

    private void drag_data_received_cb(Gtk.Widget sender,
                    Gdk.DragContext drag_context,
                    int x, int y,
                    Gtk.SelectionData data,
                    uint info, uint time) {
        print("Drag data received!\n");
        // Do something

        Gtk.drag_finish (drag_context, true, false, time);
    }
}
```

This way, the uri of the file that I drop in the source view is not pasted in it and I can open the file in another tab.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're trying to drag the file into the SourceView widget with the idea that it will open a new tab instead of opening that file in that source view widget.

What you need to do is not disable the drag event, you need to redirect it. The event will come into the sourceview widget and then you connect to it and pass it to your code (in your window?) which deals with opening a new tab.

Does this make sense? do you need code samples?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I'm gonna try to do this. But, if you have code samples, they'll be very useful. Thank you very much.

Comment: No, sorry, but when you complete, please post back here with the code sample.